# How to set .Rprofile to clean workspace and history automatically in R?

Tags: r, settings

I usually don't want to save workspace and history in R so that to keep the console clean. I am trying to put `rm(list=ls())`  in my .Rprofile, but it doesn't work. The workspace still restored from `/Users/xxx/.RData` as well as the History. Does anybody know how to set the .Rprofile to clean workspace and history automatically every time when I start R console?

Comment: Why at the start and not at the end of an R session?

Comment: Unless you are opening an existing workspace (e.g. "workspace.Rdata"), R should start "clean".

Comment: I guess they're equivalent?

Comment: You could try `.Last <- function()rm(list=ls())` or overwrite the default argument of the `quit` function.

Comment: Start R with the `--no-resore` option.

Comment: I start R not from terminal, how to set --no-resore?

Comment: There isn't really a good reason to keep your environment clean. And there is absolutely no reason to clear your history.  But if you don't want to load `.Rdata` probably the easiest thing is to put a `.Last` command to write your environment to, e.g., `nothere.Rdata` . That way you save your data but not to the default filename.

Comment: I run `rm(list=ls())` and put .last command to .Rprofile, but in a new console, ls() still show a long list of objects.

Comment: Maybe you have to remove your old workspace RData file before?

Comment: I manually removed .RData from terminal and create a new empty .RData. It finally works. Thanks sgibb..